# How can i change the header of yii grid view for check box

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

I am using Yii and showing the data on front end . I have a field for status (active or not). I am displaying in grid view like this

```
array(
                        'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn',
                        'selectableRows' => 2,
                        'header'=>"Status",
                        'checked'=>function($data, $row) use ($current_reviewers)
                            {
                                return in_array($data->rem_status, $current_reviewers);
                                }
                        ),
```

it is displaying the data correctly . But it is showing the checkbox in the column heading like in the link [link to image](http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/164686/b7174d137c0133c2d98f727799303909).

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'selectableRows'=>2` will put a checkbox in the header . Please remove that line and try